# Sind die Wendungen "etw. über die Bühne bringen/kriegen" Synonyme?

Tags: difference

Vor wenigen Tag bin ich auf die umgangssprachliche Wendung "etwas über die Bühne kriegen" gestoßen. [Im Netz findet man allerdings nur "etw. über die Bühne **bringen**".](https://www.redensarten-index.de/mobil/#suchbegriff=~~etwas%20%C3%BCber%20die%20B%C3%BChne%20bringen&bool=relevanz&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_ou) 
Ich weiß, dass normalerweise *bekommen* und *kriegen* in den meisten Wendungen austauschbar sind, natürlich, was die Bedeutung angeht und nicht die Sprachebene. In diesem Fall weiß ich jedoch nicht, ob die beiden Wendungen die gleiche Bedeutung haben.

Comment: Das sind schon deswegen keine Synonyme, weil *kriegen* deutlich Umgangssprache ist; schreiben würde ich das gar nicht.

Comment: Siehe auch Ergänzung in meiner Antwort: bin mir nicht sicher, ob das System über die Edits benachrichtigt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ich persönlich kenne es nur als

> etwas über die Bühne kriegen (1)

aber du hast schon recht, "kriegen" und "bringen" sind in solcherlei Verwendung manchmal austauschbar, also nähme es mich nicht wunder, wäre auch "bringen" in mancher deutschen Sprachregion in Gebrauch. Dagegen gibt es definitiv

> etwas auf die Bühne bringen (5)

Zu "bringen" fällt mir allerdings eher ein:

> jemanden um die Ecke bringen (2)

was nun wiederum eindeutig nicht mit "jemanden um die Ecke kriegen" ersetzt werden kann. Während

> jemanden rumkriegen (3)

nur in dieser Form verwendet wird, wohlabgegrenzt von

> jemanden umbringen (2)

was etwas ganz anderes ist als

> jemanden flachlegen (4)

aber durchaus etwas ähnliches wie

> jemanden umlegen (2)

---

(1) to manage something to happen (2) to kill somebody (3) to convince somebody to do something against his/her initial lack of enthusiasm (4) to make somebody agree in undertaking joint sexual activities (5) to produce a play, or metaphorically: to make something be a topic

Comment: Ich kenne es auch nur als "Über die Bühne bringen", Aber ich würde sagen, das "kriegen" bedeutet, dass man es geschafft hat, es über die Bühne zu bringen. <g> Man kriegt es hin.

Answer (score 4):

"Etwas über die Bühne kriegen" gibt es nicht - das ist ein Irrläufer.

Es gibt nur "etwas. über die Bühne **bringen**", mit der Bedeutung "etwas [erfolgreich] durchführen"; siehe zum Beispiel auch den [Wiktionary-Eintrag](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/etwas_%C3%BCber_die_B%C3%BChne_bringen) dazu.

---

Allerdings gibt es den Ausdruck ["etwas hin**kriegen**"](https://de.thefreedictionary.com/hinkriegen), der in seiner Hauptbedeutung dem "etwas über die Bühne **bringen**" sehr ähnlich ist: "etwas erfolgreich tun, etwas hinbekommen".

Das "etwas über die Bühne *kriegen*" scheint mir eine Kreuzung aus "etwas über die Bühne **bringen**" und "etwas hin**kriegen**" zu sein; das hat eine gewisse Witzigkeit.

Comment: Ha ha! Offenbar sind wir in unterschiedlichen Ecken des deutschen Sprachraums sozialisiert. Siehe gesonderte Antwort unten!

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Ja, ich weiß. Aber genau deswegen darf ja auch jeder seine eigene Antwort schreiben. Sonst müssten wir alle dieselbe Auffassung haben und mehrere Antworten ergäben keinen Sinn. :-) - Nach Deinem Edit passt mein Kommentar nicht mehr ganz, aber anzupassen ist es mir nun zu mühselig.